# UINavigationBar in Storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar

I just inherited a project that was made entirely in Storyboards.  I have to fix some issues with spacing and poor management of art assets after segues and I'm having trouble getting at certain components.

My issue is this: The app is based off a `UINavigationController` hierarchy and the main screen does not require a `UINavigationBar` (and it screws with the spacing of the images when it first loads).

Project needs to be iOS 5.1 compliant (so no Autolayout or iOS 6 only features).

I need to hide the `UINavigationBar` when the app starts.

I can get it to "dismiss" after the app loads by doing this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    /* Hide UINavigationBar for iPhone until a segue is performed*/

    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];

}
```

Even changing `animated:NO` gives the same result.

As a quick rundown, I have tried this in `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear`.

Since it's dismissing **after** the view has loaded, I think calling to hide the NavigationBar in the appDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method would do the trick, but because of the StoryBoard's I'm not sure how to get access to the Storyboard's Navigation Controller within the App Delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the initial NavigationController the programmatically pushed to a `UINavigationController` after the initial `ViewController` in the Storyboard.

It was the longer way to do it (4+ hours ago) but ended up working for me.

Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I may be barking up the wrong tree here, but can't you just set it through the storyboards? Under "Simulated Metrics" you can define the TopBar for each single viewController, simply setting it to "None" for the main-screen's viewController.

Comment: Simulated Metrics are only simulated - they help you space out your UI components if the event you have say a UINavigationBar, a UIToolbar and a UISearchDisplay all on the same screen, Simulated Metrics allow you to see how the screen would look but you don't get access to those objects.

Comment: Fair enough. I thought you simply didn't need the navigationBar on the start screen at all. But if it is depending on some other state, then that certainly complicates things.

Comment: Appreciate the help, it's very possible it's something that I've overlooked.  I've been jumping to other portions of the project but I keep coming back to this thinking I have a fresh mind about it and get stuck again :\

Answer (score 0):

How about just moving the nav bar off the screen instead?

Comment: I've tried changing the `UINavigationBar`'s frame by creating a CGRect and assigning the new rect to the nav bar's frame but nothing changes.